# Unable to add "android.app.Fragment" to FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I'm trying to add a 3rd party android.app.Fragment into a FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getParent().getSupportFragmentManager());            
        adapter.addFrag(getMapFragment() /* Fragment of type "android.app.Fragment" */, "Add me!!!");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

but I get the follwing compilation error in the "addFrag" line:

> "wrong 1st argument type. Found: android.app.Fragment, required: android.support.v4.app.Fragment"

I've read that all support libraries are supposed to be backward-compatible, so how is it that I can't add the old Fragment to my adapter?

Comment: The 3rd party fragment does not extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` so you can't use the support library adapter.

Comment: just import android.support.v4.app.Fragment. because FragmentPagerAdapter uses v4 support library for fragment

Comment: Isn't there a support map Fragment class?

Comment: I'm using a 3rd party MapFragment over which I have no control, so the question basically boils down to can I add an older-versioned fragment to a ViewPager and if not, why?

Comment: `android.app.Fragment` is not an older version. The support one makes fragments available on older Android versions where no `android.app.Fragment` exists.

Comment: @dharms Isn't the support library backwards-compatible?

Comment: If you want to support your fragment to multiple API levels. Then you should use v4 support library. So that android.support.v4.app.Fragment is required.

Comment: @JimmyLeeJones you are actually thinking about it backwards. The support library is to bring fragment functionality to versions of android prior to the release of fragments. Your 3rd party library is not using these support libraries, or at least the class you are using is not. Perhaps there is a support version as well?

Comment: @dharms I think my understainding of Fragments is not so good, so you're probably right. Assuming I can't change the 3rd party Fragment, what would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: If there is no support version of the fragment offered, you will need to convert your code to not use the support library classes.

Comment: @jimmy all you need to do is use the FragmentPagerAdapter from the v13 support library instead of the v4 one.

Comment: @DanielNugent I'm giving it a shot right now, thanks

Comment: @DanielNugent It did the trick, thanks a lot